# d3.js Node "jumps back" on fast drag in force layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using a force layout with zero-gravity and charge value:

```
var force = d3.layout.force()
    .gravity(0)
    .charge(0)
    .friction(0.9)
    .linkDistance(250)
    .linkStrength(1)
    .size([width, height])
    .on("tick", tick);

function tick(e) {
    d.y = Math.max(d.radius, Math.min(height - d.radius, d.y));
    d.x = Math.max(d.radius, Math.min(width - d.radius, d.x));

    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
});
        }
```

There is a circle. And problem is when I do a fast drag, the circle "jumps back". Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

CodePen: http://codepen.io/vanquang9387/pen/gpLpGE?editors=001

Comment: could you provide a JSFiddle ?

Comment: @thisOneGuy: I can't make it work with JSFiddle on sharing. I've updated with CodePen link. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Dirty fix

Change this...

```
.friction(0.9)
```

to this...

```
.friction(0)
```

### Background

Inside the force layout module in d3, there is a `force.tick` method that is called before every animation frame.  This is where the node positions are recalculated.  There is a calculation for links which takes into account link `strength`, `weights` and the target `linkDistance`; a `gravity` calculation which is a function of the distance of each node from the center of the layout; and a charge calculation which is based on the `charge`, the `chargeDistance` and the relative position of the nodes.  There is also a calculation for `friction`.  All of these - except for the `friction` calculation - take into account the current "temperature" of the layout (`alpha`), which is really just an exponentially decaying value that is a function of how many ticks have elapsed since the layout was started.

These calculations are sequentially applied to all of the elements of the layout, the input positions for each step being the output of the previous.  But "fixed" nodes are treated differently for the friction calculation and nodes being dragged are `fixed` by the drag behavior.

`friction` is not really "friction", it's more like velocity decay as explained in the [WIKI](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#friction),   The `friction` calculation is meant to maintain the velocity of the nodes by moving them away from their position at the end of the previous tick (`px`, `py`).  The distance moved away is proportional to the velocity of each node which is based on the distance between (`px`, `py`) and the position calculated by the previous steps (links, charge and gravity) in the current `tick` (in reality it's a little more complicated than that because the charge calculation is actually "non-causal" and changes the previous positions, but this doesn't affect the principle of the friction calculation).

During the drag, (`px`, `py`) is updated with the mouse position by the drag behavior on every `mousemove`.  *Then*, on the next tick, these values are copied to (`x`, `y`) in the force layout.  So, during the drag, the *previous* position is actually the *current* position and vice versa!  Therefore, when the drag ends, the velocity used in the friction calculation is in the *opposite direction to it's actual velocity*, so the `friction` calc tries to maintain this... and that's why it jumps back.

### Dead stop

My next move would be to find a way to set (`px`, `py`) to (`x`, `y`) in the `dragend` event handler.
Like this for example...

```
  var stdDragEnd = force.drag().on("dragend.force");
  force.drag().on("dragend.force", myDragEnd);
  function myDragEnd(d) {
    d.px = d.x; d.py = d.y;
    stdDragEnd.call(this, d)
  }
```

You can put this anywhere in the code where your `force` variable is already defined.  The idea is to hook the standard behaviour rather than replace it.

Now, even if you set friction to 1.0, the node will stop dead after the dragend.
You don't need to preserve the `this` context based on the current state of the code by the way, but anyway, it's good practice I guess.  Who knows what the future will bring lah ;)

Comment: It seems to work. But, this will slows down motion when I add more nodes and links and with a negative charge value. Isn't it?

Comment: Thanks for detail explaination. I'm trying with dragend event.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. But now I want to make a inertial drag instead of "dead stop". Like this with other nodes and links: http://bl.ocks.org/pjanik/5872514
I think it's hard to implement :(

Comment: @Quang that's a new question. You were only asking about jumping back and I answered that so its better if you accept my answer and ask a new question.  I'll help you on that as well...

Comment: @Quang, by the way, the link you give is using an older version (3.2.2) of d3 and it has a completely different drag behavior module which includes an inertia method which has since disappeared...

Comment: @Quang I got interested in this whole thing and I can help with your other requirements.  If you still need help, post another question with a title about inertial drag in force layout and I will show you how to do it.  I think that would be better than making my answer here even longer...

Comment: My new question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30480313/inertial-drag-in-force-layout  P.S: don't know why I can't mention you in comment @Cool Blue