# Inertial drag in force layout

Tags: d3.js

I'm using lastest d3js with force layout to create interactive graph like this:
[image]

Requirements are:

1. Nodes can be dragged (inertial drag)
2. Node bounces back when hitting border.
3. Nodes don't overlap each other (I can do this based on Collision Detection sample)

Somebody please help me with 1 & 2.

The background for this question is in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30387784/d3-js-node-jumps-back-on-fast-drag-in-force-layout) related question.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Background

The background for this answer is in my answer to a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30433664/2670182).

That question was about why nodes jump back after release and the main point to bring from there is that, during `force.drag` behavior the previous node positions, (d.px, d.py) and the current positions (d.x, d.y) are actually reversed.  So, when the drag is released, the initial velocity is therefor reversed, causing the jump back behavior.
This is actually due to the drag behavior updating the *previous position* on drag events and the internal `force.tick` method copying the previous values onto the current values each position calculation.  (I'm sure there is a good reason for this by the way, I suspect it is related to [this](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/commit/5390ac3f853e6f48b4db66dd81e97885bbea530b#diff-4a071b45d339d9775f11dbc82181dc2e)...)

### Inertial dragging

In order to implement inertial dragging, this velocity reversal needs to be corrected, so the current and previous points need to be *reversed* immediately after `dragend`.

This is a good start, but a couple of other problems remain:

1. Velocity state is lost every tick when previous position is copied to the current position.
2. "Sticky node" behavior (on `mouseover`) is re-established on `dragend` which tends to re-capture the nodes and defeat the inertial effect.

The first one means that if a tick occurs between releasing the drag and correcting the velocity, i.e. immediately after `dragend`, then the velocity will be zero and the node will stop dead.  This happens often enough to be annoying.  One solution is to maintain a record of `d3.event.dx` and `d3.event.dy` and use these to modify (d.px, d.py) on `dragend`.  This also avoids the problem caused by the reversal of previous and current points.

The second remaining problem can be fixed by delaying the sticky node behavior reinstatement until after `mouseout`.  A small delay after `mouseout` is advisable in case the mouse immediately re-enters the node *after* `mouseout`.

### Implimentation

The basic strategy to implement the above two corrections is to hook the drag events in the force layout in the former and the mouse events in the force layout in the later.  For defensive reasons, the standard callbacks for the various hooks are stored on the `datum` object of the nodes and retrieved from there when un-hooking.

The friction parameter is set to 1 in the code which means they maintain their velocity indefinitely, to see a steady inertial effect set it to 0.9... I jest like the bouncing balls.

```js
$(function() {
  var width = 1200,
    height = 800;
  var circles = [{
      x: width / 2 + 100,
      y: height / 2,
      radius: 100
    }, {
      x: width / 2 - 100,
      y: height / 2,
      radius: 100
    }, ],
    nodeFill = "#006E3C";

  var force = d3.layout.force()
    .gravity(0)
    .charge(-100)
    .friction(1)
    .size([width, height])
    .nodes(circles)
    .linkDistance(250)
    .linkStrength(1)
    .on("tick", tick)
    .start();

  SliderControl("#frictionSlider", "friction", force.friction, [0, 1], ",.3f");

  var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .style("background-color", "white");
  var nodes = svg.selectAll(".node");
  nodes = nodes.data(circles);
  nodes.exit().remove();
  var enterNode = nodes.enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .call(force.drag);
  console.log(enterNode);
  //Add circle to group
  enterNode.append("circle")
    .attr("r", function(d) {
      return d.radius;
    })
    .style("fill", "#006E3C")
    .style("opacity", 0.6);

  ;
  (function(d3, force) {
    //Drag behaviour///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //  hook drag behavior on force

    //VELOCITY
    //  maintain velocity state in case a force tick occurs emidiately before dragend
    //  the tick wipes out the previous position
    var dragVelocity = (function() {
      var dx, dy;

      function f(d) {
        if (d3.event) {
          dx = d3.event.dx;
          dy = d3.event.dy;
        }
        return {
          dx: dx,
          dy: dy
        }
      };
      f.correct = function(d) {
        //tick occured and set px/y to x/y, re-establish velocity state
        d.px = d.x - dx;
        d.py = d.y - dy;
      }
      f.reset = function() {
        dx = dy = 0
      }
      return f;
    })()

    //DRAGSTART HOOK
    var stdDragStart = force.drag().on("dragstart.force");

    force.drag().on("dragstart.force", myDragStart);

    function myDragStart(d) {
        var that = this,
          node = d3.select(this);

        nonStickyMouse();
        dragVelocity.reset();
        stdDragStart.call(this, d)

        function nonStickyMouse() {

          if (!d.___hooked) {
            //node is not hooked
            //hook mouseover/////////////////////////
            //remove sticky node on mouseover behavior and save listeners
            d.___mouseover_force = node.on("mouseover.force");
            node.on("mouseover.force", null);

            d.___mouseout_force = node.on("mouseout.force");

            d.___hooked = true;

            //standard mouseout will clear d.fixed
            d.___mouseout_force.call(that, d);
          }
          //dissable mouseout/////////////////////////
          node.on("mouseout.force", null);
        }
      }
      //DRAG HOOK
    var stdDrag = force.drag().on("drag.force");

    force.drag().on("drag.force", myDrag);

    function myDrag(d) {
      var v, p;
      //maintain back-up velocity state
      v = dragVelocity();
      p = {
        x: d3.event.x,
        y: d3.event.y
      };
      stdDrag.call(this, d)
    }

    //DRAGEND HOOK
    var stdDragEnd = force.drag().on("dragend.force");

    force.drag().on("dragend.force", myDragEnd);

    function myDragEnd(d) {
      var that = this,
        node = d3.select(this);
      //correct the final velocity vector at drag end
      dragVelocity.correct(d)

      //hook mouseout/////////////////////////
      //re-establish standard behavior on mouseout
      node.on("mouseout.force", function mouseout(d) {
        myForceMouseOut.call(this, d)
      });

      stdDragEnd.call(that, d);

      function myForceMouseOut(d) {
        var timerID = window.setTimeout((function() {
          var that = this,
            node = d3.select(this);
          return function unhookMouseover() {
            //if (node.on("mouseover.force") != d.___mouseout_force) {
            if (node.datum().___hooked) {
              //un-hook mouseover and mouseout////////////
              node.on("mouseout.force", d.___mouseout_force);
              node.on("mouseover.force", d.___mouseover_force);
              node.datum().___hooked = false;
            }
          }
        }).call(this), 500);
        return timerID;
      }
    }

  })(d3, force);

  function tick(e) {
    //contain the nodes...
    nodes.attr("transform", function(d) {
      var r = 100;
      if (d.x - r <= 0 && d.px > d.x) d.px -= (d.px - d.x) * 2;
      if (d.x + r >= width && d.px < d.x) d.px += (d.x - d.px) * 2;
      if (d.y - r <= 0 && d.py > d.y) d.py -= (d.py - d.y) * 2;
      if (d.y + r >= height && d.py < d.y) d.py += (d.y - d.py) * 2;
      return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    });
    //indicate status by color
    nodes.selectAll("circle")
      .style("fill", function(d, i) {
        return ((d.___hooked && !d.fixed) ? "red" : nodeFill)
      })
    force.start();
  }

  function SliderControl(selector, title, value, domain, format) {
    var accessor = d3.functor(value),
      rangeMax = 1000,
      _scale = d3.scale.linear().domain(domain).range([0, rangeMax]),
      _$outputDiv = $("<div />", {
        class: "slider-value"
      }),
      _update = function(value) {
        _$outputDiv.css("left", 'calc( ' + (_$slider.position().left + _$slider.outerWidth()) + 'px + 1em )')
        _$outputDiv.text(d3.format(format)(value));
        $(".input").width(_$outputDiv.position().left + _$outputDiv.outerWidth() - _innerLeft)

      },

      _$slider = $(selector).slider({
        value: _scale(accessor()),
        max: rangeMax,
        slide: function(e, ui) {
          _update(_scale.invert(ui.value));
          accessor(_scale.invert(ui.value)).start();
        }
      }),
      _$wrapper = _$slider.wrap("<div class='input'></div>")
      .before($("<div />").text(title + ":"))
      .after(_$outputDiv).parent(),
      _innerLeft = _$wrapper.children().first().position().left;

    _update(_scale.invert($(selector).slider("value")))

  };

});
```

```css
body {
  /*font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;*/
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
svg {
  outline: 1px solid black;
  background-color: rgba(255, 127, 80, 0.6);
}
div {
  display: inline-block;
}
#method,
#clear {
  margin-left: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 127, 80, 0.6);
  border: none;
}
#clear {
  float: right;
}
#inputs {
  font-size: 16px;
  display: block;
  width: 900px;
}
.input {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgba(255, 127, 80, 0.37);
  outline: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
  padding: 3px 10px;
}
.input div {
  width: 60px;
}
.method {
  display: block;
}
.ui-slider,
span.ui-slider-handle.ui-state-default {
  width: 3px;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 0;
}
span.ui-slider-handle.ui-state-default {
  top: calc(50% - 1em / 2);
  height: 1em;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
}
div.ui-slider-horizontal {
  width: 200px;
  margin: auto 10px auto 10px;
  /*position: absolute;*/
  /*bottom: 0.1em;*/
  position: absolute;
  bottom: calc(50% - 2.5px);
  /*vertical-align: middle;*/
  height: 5px;
  border: none;
}
.slider-value {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: right;
}
input,
select,
button {
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="inputs">

  <div id="frictionSlider"></div>
</div>
```